# checking an element is clicked not working jquery

Tags: jquery, css, click

I have a dialog box which get list of students from an ajax call and I am loading the data with `.html()` method of jquery.

I put the html data like this into the dialog box.I want to make each student name clickable.When I click first,the background of selected `.student_list_div` should be `green`. If I click again,I should make it `background none`.If clicked again, the color should be green in order to make the user know that it is selected or not.I have done the jquery method also.But its not working properly.

```
<a href='' class='student_list' id='studentid1'><div class="student_list_div">
StudentName1</div></a>
<a href='' class='student_list' id='studentid2'><div class="student_list_div">
StudentName2</div></a>
and so on.......
```

My jquery method is like this.

```
 $("#dialog_wrapper").on('click','.student_list',function(){
            if($(this).data('clicked'))
            {
               $(this).find('.student_list_div').css('background-color','none'); 
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).click(function(){
                   $(this).data('clicked',true); 
                   $(this).find('.student_list_div').css('background-color','green');
                });
            }


            return false;
        });
```

Please help me

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why are you binding another click event handler. remove `$(this).click(function(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind an additional click event handler within your first click event handler. Also I think you aren't changing the clicked property to false if it is true.

```js
 $("#dialog_wrapper").on('click', '.student_list', function() {
   if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
     $(this).find('.student_list_div').css('background-color', 'none');
     $(this).data('clicked', false);
   } else {
     $(this).data('clicked', true);
     $(this).find('.student_list_div').css('background-color', 'green');
   }


   return false;
 });
```

Also you could achieve the same effect by having a '.clicked' class and using jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to toggle it when clicked.

```js
$("#dialog_wrapper").on('click', '.student_list', function() {
  $(this).find('.student_list_div').toggleClass('.clicked')
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: The second version (toggling a class) is definitely a better option. Note the original HTML was also invalid to begin with (a div is a *block* element so is not valid inside an anchor which is an *inline* element)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from any other issues, *inline* elements, like an anchor, cannot contain *block* elements (like a div).

Instead use `<span>`s for the inner elements.

Comment: I have used span,but also background color is not going once it is selected.

Comment: You are also connecting a click handler inside a click handler - never a good idea.

Comment: I understood my mistake.Thanks for making me aware.I have upvoted your answer too

Answer (score 1):

You are binding click event handler inside click handler. Remove `$(this).click(function(){`

Use

```
 $("#dialog_wrapper").on('click', '.student_list', function() {
    if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
        $(this).find('.student_list_div').css('background-color', '');
    } else {
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
        $(this).find('.student_list_div').css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    return false;
 });
```

Important: anchor *a* can't contain `div`, use `span` instead

Comment: This is working for first time.That is if it is not anchor tag is not clicked,it will make background green on first click.If I click again,background color is not removing

Comment: @Techy, try with `.css('background-color', '')`

Comment: This is also not working.When I added $(this).data('clicked', false); inside the first if condition it worked.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is event binding of dynamically created elements. See this:

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)